# Strange message when saving a plot in pdf format with Matplotlib, why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, output

I am producing some plots using `Matplotlib` (v 3.2.2) and the `mplhep` tu embed the style used by my collaboration. I noticed that, if I save plots with .png format the output is normal, but if I save them in .pdf I got this message:

```
'texgyreheros-regular.otf' can not be subsetted into a Type 3 font. The entire font will be embedded in the output.
```

However it seems that the output plot is always ok. Do you know how to "correct" this or at least hide this sort of warning message? Thanks!

The function I am using to plot is the following:

```
def PlotVarVsTime( dataframe, title, channel ):
    """
    Function used to plot each row of the dataframe and save it.

    Args:
        dataframe ( dataframe ): the interested dataframe.
        title ( string ): the variable name for plot title.
        channel ( string ): the channel name.
    """   
    
    # Filling a plot, for each dataframe row, with points
    print( "Making plots...", end = "\n" )
    for row_index in dataframe.index:
        
        # Filling single plot for the correspinding row
        columns_container = np.array( [] )
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        for column in dataframe.loc[ :, dataframe.columns != "Channel" ]:
            x = Decimal( column )
            y = dataframe[ column ][ row_index ]
            ax.scatter( x, y, c = "blue" )
            columns_container = np.append( columns_container, column )
        
        # Plot settings
        time_start = ft.IntToTime( int( columns_container[ 0 ] ) )
        time_end = ft.IntToTime( int( columns_container[ -1 ] ) )
        ax.set_title( dataframe[ "Channel" ][ row_index ] + "\n" + "(" + time_start + " - " + time_end + ")", fontsize = 15 )
        ax.set_xlabel( "Time (yy/mm/dd/h/m/s)", fontsize = 15 )
        ax.set_ylabel( title, fontsize = 15 )
        ax.set_xlim( columns_container[ 0 ], columns_container[ -1 ] )
        ax.tick_params( axis = 'both', labelsize = 13 )
        ax.xaxis.offsetText.set_fontsize( 15 )

        # Saving plot
        output_name = ft.NameToStr( dataframe[ "Channel" ][ row_index ] )
        print( "Doing " + output_name + " plots..." )
        
        fig.canvas.start_event_loop( sys.float_info.min ) # Workaround for Exception in Tkinter callback
        plt.savefig( "img/" + channel + "/" + title + "/pdf/" + output_name + ".pdf", bbox_inches = "tight", dpi = 100 );
        fig.canvas.start_event_loop( sys.float_info.min ) # Workaround for Exception in Tkinter callback
        plt.savefig( "img/" + channel + "/" + title + "/png/" + output_name + ".png", bbox_inches = "tight", dpi = 100 )
        plt.clf()
        plt.close()
        
        columns_container = np.array( [] )
        
    print()
    print( "Plots have been saved in:", end = "\n" )
    print( "- PDF:", ft.Colored( "img/" + channel + "/" + title + "/pdf/", cl.OutColor.green ), end = "\n" )
    print( "- PNG:", ft.Colored( "img/" + channel + "/" + title + "/png/", cl.OutColor.green ), end = "\n" )
```

**EDIT 1**

I am using the option:

```
plt.style.use( hep.style.ATLAS )
```

from [mplhep](https://github.com/scikit-hep/mplhep) library.

Comment: Hey, do you get the message if you don't save the plot as a `pdf` but only save it as `png`?

Comment: No, I get it only if I save it as pdf. If I save it as png everything is ok.

Comment: @KJ thanks, however this is not a problem since I have to produce plots on my computer only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this issue. The problem was due to the usage of an older version of Matplotlib. Once I've updated the module the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to change the type of your font as type 3 seems not be supported for PDFs.

Try changing `fonttype` to 42.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.rcParams['pdf.fonttype'] = 42
matplotlib.rcParams['ps.fonttype'] = 42
```

**Source: http://phyletica.org/matplotlib-fonts/

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work...

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce the message with MPL version '3.4.3'. Can you provide example inputs to test your function?

Comment: A thing that can help you is that I am also using the option `plt.style.use( hep.style.ATLAS )` from mplhep library: https://github.com/scikit-hep/mplhep

Comment: I have tried the `mplhep` version '0.3.23' and still can not reproduce the message.